# Differing Apache Solr results when doing queries through Drupal – why?

Tags: drupal, solr

I'm trying to create a custom search interface for [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) using [Drupal](http://drupal.org), and I'm having some strange issues with the results.

I have the same query yielding 8 hits when I run it from Solr's built-in web interface, and 0 hits when I run it through Drupal. Can anyone explain why?

Here's the queries, both taken from the Solr log:

- Solr backend

  > `INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select params={wt=standard&rows=10&start=0&explainOther=&hl.fl=&indent=on&q=ss_cck_field_goal:sell+AND+ss_cck_field_type:(own+OR+coop+OR+house+OR+commercial)+AND+is_price:[10000+TO+5560000]&fl=*,score&qt=standard&version=2.2} hits=8 status=0 QTime=2`
- Drupal ApacheSolr module

  > `09-Mar-2009 15:37:31 org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
  >   INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select params={wt=json&rows=10&json.nl=map&start=0&q=ss_cck_field_goal:sell+AND+ss_cck_field_type:(own+OR+coop+OR+house+OR+commercial)+AND+is_price:[10000+TO+5560000]&version=1.2} hits=0 status=0 QTime=9`

The only thing that sticks out in my eyes is the `version=1.2` parameter, but I've tried removing it, and that doesn't change the behavior.

After lots of tweaking, I've managed to the Drupal module to send more or less the same parameters, but it still gives 0 results:

> `09-Mar-2009 17:47:43 org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
>   INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select params={wt=standard&rows=10&start=0&q=ss_cck_field_goal:sell+AND+ss_cck_field_type:(own+OR+coop+OR+house+OR+commercial)+AND+is_price:[10000+TO+5560000]} hits=0 status=0 QTime=13`

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [request handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRequestHandler) (qt parameter) might be different. When not defined (the Drupal query doesn't define it) Solr uses the default handler. Maybe the default handler configured is not the standard request handler... check your solrconfig.xml

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. The solrconfig.xml that comes with the Drupal module sets the default handler to dismax. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

could it be that there should be a non-empty `fl` (field list) parameter in the Drupal query? no fields to display: no results?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion…
I just tried (wt=standard&rows=10&start=0&fl=title&…) but that appears to have no effect…