# No Search Results

Tags: search, drupal, solr

I installed apache solr on drupal 5, now when I perform a search using Admin I get results but I do not get any from Drupal.

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626938 ?

Comment: Mausch, could you please break it down for me.

I am not using a custom presentation but rather a default one ad its not working.

Comment: Maybe you could give us more detail?  It doesn't seem the one-line description is resulting in many answers.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a permissions issue. 
Since you can access search results from admin, the search engine and -indexing is working. 
Drupal admin search returns all entries, regardless of their status (published, unpublished, draft) or their access (many flavours of content-access modules exist).

First, verify that the nodes are actually visible on your site as "normal" user: anonymous or loggin in. If so, there is not an access-problem and nodes are published.
Secondly, verify that you have no access-module, such as organic groups or domain running: that may be configured slightly wrong, or used in a strange way, and disable access to content under certain conditions. 
Thirdly, verify that you are not running any search-related modules. Maybe you installed a module that "enhances" or "overrides" search? Such a module would not change the behaviour of admin-search, but would change what is seen at the search results.

If none of these apply, then please post more infomation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd double check that Drupal has permission to create temporary tables within the database. If not, you'll always get 'no results found' when searching.